# Is Elementor Page Builder Plugin working on multisite wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

## **Implementation**

- We are using the Elementor page builder plugin to design Wordpress pages and blogs and 
   perfectly worked on a basic Wordpress setup. 
   (i.e Default Wordpress Setup using a single theme).
- Now, We need to use the same Wordpress set up as a multisite and installed Elementor Page 
  Builder for an independent site across a multisite network.

## **Problem**

- Elementor shows **403 Forbidden error** while updating template design of the secondary site.

## **Questions**

1. Is there any idea why the elementor behaves like this?
2. Is Elementor Pro Plugin really supported by the multisite Wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
However, for Elementor Pro, you will need to activate a license key for each of your sites. Note: You have to accept the automatic updates via the main site when you work with a multisite installation.